# How to use class in java

Tags: java, class, gwt, gwt2

I am new to GWT and java
Here is example to understand my problem

Code

```
  .Client

  Class A(){
// design Part with 2 text box for user name and password
//On click event of Button  asyncInterface is called (RPC) to create a session

service.getConnection(authentication, callback);// authentication is array with username password

}
```

on SERVER side

```
 .server
public class ServiceIMPL extends RemoteServiceServlet implements ServiceInterface{
     public String getConnection(String[] authentication) {
        connectionParameter = new ConnectionParameter(authentication,repositoryName);
        session=connectionParameter.getSession();
     }
 }
```

This Session is used to for adding deleting the folder in the repository.

the addFolder, getFolder,getDocment methods are written in same class as Session required  to do so.Every thing is working fine.

Now i have to addDocument in the repository. For which i have design a servlet in server

```
 public class FileUpload extends HttpServlet implements Servlet {

// servlet is also working fine i have the content of file in buffer.
//but to add file in a repository I need Session which is in ServiceIMPL Class
//if I create a object of ServiceIMPL class then the authentication will be null
//Without Username and Pass word session cannot be created.
}
```

Please help me how to do it.

Comment: What have you tried so far and what problems have you encountered? What research have you done up to this point?

Comment: @pap   I want the session which is in ServiceIMPL.
if i create a object of ServiceIMPL in FileUpload class. then authentication array will be null as it is a new object.
and the authentication array is provided by the client.

Comment: If you are new check gwt-dispatch and guice documentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Class ServiceImpl 
make the session public

```
    public Session session;
```

and in  class File Upload

```
  private Session session = ServiceImpl.session;
```

I gurantee this will work. but this is not the good way of coding.
wait till any Expert reply.

Comment: So how does this work, where does the ServiceImpl object come from? or is session in ServiceImpl static?

Comment: @HilbrandBouwkamp : I guess if the variable of the class is public then u can use it any where in the project.
So ClassName.variablename in anyother class will give the same value ,as it is already intialized it that class.

Comment: @NewCodeLearner If it's public you still need an instance of that class to access it; `ServiceImpl` must be a variable unless session is a `static` field: `public static Session session;`? In any case I think this answer is incorrect, but I just want to check how incorrect.. So therefor I'm wondering how this answer actually works, before replying what's wrong.

Comment: @HilbrandBouwkamp  It is obvious the session should be static.

Comment: @GameBuilder I was already afraid of that.... That means this answer is something you should NEVER do!!! Because the webserver manages the instances they are reused among different sessions. This means as soon as 2 users access the site, the static variable will be set by the user last using this variable. In general it's forbidden to store user specific state in (static) variables in servlets, as you have no control over these servlets. To get a session use the session provided by the webserver, as I described in my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9633786/66416

Comment: @HilbrandBouwkamp  : Understood your point. even i am new to java and GWt.

Answer (score 0):

What kind of session do you use? If it is a `HttpSession` you can simply do `request.getSession()` from the `HttpServletRequest request` parameter in `doGet` in your `FileUpload` servlet.